# Change ViewController on AlertView click

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on a tabbed application.

I have 2 view controllers: ViewControllerA, ViewControllerB.

ViewControllerA is a tab bar controller, and ViewControllerB is a regular ViewController.

On ViewController A, an alert view appears, when clicking on one of the buttons it should go to ViewControllerB:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Anything"])
   {
        ViewControllerB *controllerB = [self.storyboard istantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"]
        [self presentViewController:controllerB animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Now, on ViewControllerB, which is not a Tab Bar Controller, when I press on a button, it should go to ViewControllerA, and the Tab Bar should appear again.
Here's the method:

```
ViewControllerA *controllerA = [self.storyboard istantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerA"];

[self presentViewController:controllerA animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem is, when I press on the button on ViewControllerB, which should bring me to the Tab Bar Controller, it does switch to ViewControllerA, but the Tab Bar does not appear.

So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are many different ways to display a view controller. Plenty of tutorials are available.

Comment: So your question really has nothing to do with the alert view, correct? If you don't know how to present a view controller, please go read the `View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: @MohamedGooner its better to remove this post & respost a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On pressing button on `ViewControllerB` you should write following code:

```
(void)buttonPressed
{
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ViewControllerA already has it's own Navigation Controller, an easy way to do this is instantiate the new view controller and use your navigation controller to *push* it onto the stack:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Anything"]) {
        ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
    }
}
```